# Getting protein from nuts and seeds implies consuming a lot of fat. Is that a bad thing?

Tags: protein, diet

I am considering various ways of obtaining sufficient protein from plant-based sources, particularly nuts and seeds. I am using an estimate of about 0.75g of protein per kg of body weight - for me, that's about 55g of protein per day. If I were to get all my protein from, say, peanuts, then I would also get about 150g of fat just from the nuts. That amounts to more than half of my calories for the day, and it sounds like a lot of fat consumption.

Even if I assume that I pick up protein from bread or egg/milk-based sources, just assuming that the majority of my protein came from nuts and seeds seems to imply that a majority of my dietary calories will come from fat. As far as I know, most nut and seed oils are not saturated, which (if they were) would be way above recommended intake (e.g. [nhs.uk](https://www.nhs.uk/live-well/eat-well/food-types/different-fats-nutrition/)). While I can easily find upper limits for recommended saturated fat consumption, I haven't found any consistent limits for unsaturated fat consumption.

So, assuming total calories are controlled, is the increased fat consumption a good reason not to get so much protein from nuts and seeds?

Answer (score 2):

Lentils, beans and peas are great vega sources of protein that contain little to no fat.

For more information on nuts you may read the following:
https://nutritionfacts.org/topics/nuts/